# software to zoom in/out in screen record

Tags: video, fullscreen, screen-recording

I want an open source screen recording software(using Windows 7 pro) which can also have the option to zoom in and zoom out a particular part of a screen while recording the video.I tried OBS Studio and it was recording fine but I could not find the zoom in options while recording.Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AeroZoom](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/AeroZoom.shtml). This one invokes Windows's native magnifier functionalities via keyboard shortcuts. You can use it with any screen recorder. I tried ZoomIt before but it's buggy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default solution with your operating system.
 Go to- all programs-> Windows ease of access -> Magnifier.
You can now zoom in and out using this default tool. It is so simple but looks nice. I faced the same problem with OBS, as it is lacking the zoom in or zoom out capability. After finding this that is not a problem to me.
There is another way, you can make some scenes in OBS before recording with the zooming in of the location you want to show with zoom. While recording, switch the scenes to get your preferred view. But this is too complex for me. I prefer windows magnifier for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [ZoomIt](https://zoomit.en.softonic.com/) software which has only 200 kb size and it is lot better than default window zoom. Please try it. It work perfect with OBS. well at least for me.